# Breakpoints not being hit Xamarin PCL project, only in iOS specific code

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, xamarin, breakpoints

I just installed Visual Studio for Mac in my Mac Agent server machine and now when I debug my iOS project, only the breakpoints in the specific iOS code hit. The breakpoints in the PCL project are run over with the output:

```
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'MyClass.cs:75,1' to void MyClass.<MyFunction>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00012].
```

The PCL breakpoints aren't hit.

Everything is up-to-date in both machines.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm... Looks like the problem is gone after setting the iOS Build Property "Linker Behavior" to "Don't Link".

Comment: Glad to know that it has been resolved, you could mark the answer:)

Comment: Only tomorrow :/

Comment: Thanks for your support:)